# How to modify PropertyGrid at runtime (add/remove property and dynamic types/enums)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid

How do you modify a propertygrid at runtime in every way? I want to be able to add and remove properties and add "dynamic types", what I mean with that is a type that result in a runtime generated dropdown in the propertygrid using a TypeConverter.

I have actually been able to do both those things (add/remove properties and add dynamic type) but only separately not at the same time.

To implement the support to add and remove properties at runtime I used [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/Dynamic_Propertygrid.aspx?msg=1027628) and modified the code a bit to support different types (not just strings).

```
private System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid propertyGrid1;
private CustomClass myProperties = new CustomClass();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myProperties.Add(new CustomProperty("Name", "Sven", typeof(string), false, true));
    myProperties.Add(new CustomProperty("MyBool", "True", typeof(bool), false, true));
    myProperties.Add(new CustomProperty("CaptionPosition", "Top", typeof(CaptionPosition), false, true));
    myProperties.Add(new CustomProperty("Custom", "", typeof(StatesList), false, true)); //<-- doesn't work
}

/// <summary>
/// CustomClass (Which is binding to property grid)
/// </summary>
public class CustomClass: CollectionBase,ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Add CustomProperty to Collectionbase List
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Value"></param>
    public void Add(CustomProperty Value)
    {
        base.List.Add(Value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove item from List
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Name"></param>
    public void Remove(string Name)
    {
        foreach(CustomProperty prop in base.List)
        {
            if(prop.Name == Name)
            {
                base.List.Remove(prop);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

etc...

```
public enum CaptionPosition
{
    Top,
    Left
}
```

My complete solution can be downloaded [here](http://helgo.net/salle/misc/PropertyGrid_2005.zip).

It works fine when I add strings, bools or enums, but when I try to add a "dynamic type" like StatesList it doesn't work. Does anyone know why and can help me to solve it?

```
public class StatesList : System.ComponentModel.StringConverter
{
    private string[] _States = { "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas" };

    public override System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection
    GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return new StandardValuesCollection(_States);
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The method of using a TypeConverter works fine when you don't try to add the property at runtime, for example [this code](http://www.megasolutions.net/cSharp/PropertyGrid-dynamic-Dropdown-List-4124.aspx) works without any problem, but I want to be able to do both.

Please take a look at [my project](http://helgo.net/salle/misc/PropertyGrid_2005.zip).
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you do, is adding StatesList (a TypeConverter) as a property.
What you should do, is adding a property with StatesList as its TypeConverter.

Answer (score 6):

Ah, of course!

```
myProperties.Add(new CustomProperty("Custom", "", typeof(States), false, true));

[TypeConverter(typeof(StatesList))]
public class States
{
}
```

Works like a charm, thank you!

I have updated my project, hope it can be helpful to others, it can be found [here](http://helgo.net/salle/misc/DynamicPropertyGrid_Working.zip).

Comment: I know the post is very old, but I have a short question. I user exactly your code within my application but the custom combobox doesn't work. The name of the property is greyed out and no options are available. Any idea, what I can do to fix that?

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: @user653427, Since this is such an old question, it might also be worth it to post a new question and link back to this page.  You'll be able to give more detail and reach more people that way.

Comment: To avoid the extra empty 'States' class you can also return the typeconverter in the PropertyDescriptor implementation (CustomPropertyDescriptor) in your case - the member to override is: public TypeConverter Converter

Comment: thank you , if user choose top or bottom from CaptionPosition combobox How can we get that value in  the code?

Comment: and another question is when you new a CustomProperty for CaptionPosition enum, you set "top" as a value . but when I run application,at first there isn't "top" value in captionPosition field . when I choose item from that comboBox the related value shown. How can I fix this problem? I mean define default value for combobox

Answer (score 5):

This question and answer was of great usefulness to me. However, I needed to extend things a bit further by allowing for run-time generated dropdown list values. I thought I would post some sample code in regards to what it required, in case anyone finds it useful.

First, I added an options parameter to the CustomProperty constructor and added an Options property:

```
    private List<string> lOptions;

    public CustomProperty(string sName, object value, Type tType, bool bReadOnly, bool bVisible, List<string> lOptions)
    {
        this.lOptions = lOptions;
    }

    public List<string> Options
    {
        get { return lOptions; }
    }
```

Second, I added an Options property to the CustomPropertyDescriptor class:

```
    public List<string> Options
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Property.Options;
        }
    }
```

Third, I had to modify the GetStandardValues method in my dynamic type class (i.e. StatesList) to make use of the new Options property on the CustomPropertyDescriptor Object:

```
    public override StandardValuesCollection
                 GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        CustomPropertyDescriptor descriptor = (CustomPropertyDescriptor)context.PropertyDescriptor;
        return new StandardValuesCollection(descriptor.Options);
    }
```

Finally, I had to pass in my list of options when creating a new CustomProperty object:

```
    List<string> optionsList = new List<string>(new string[] { "test1", "test2", "test3" });        
    CustomProperty myProperty = new CustomProperty(attr.Name, attr.Value, valueType, false, true, optionsList);
```

In place of the static list that I passed in for this example, you can generate the list of options for your dropdown in any manner that you please, giving you full control over the options available.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to expand on the answer, very helpful.

Comment: what is valueType ? its typeof(list<string>) ?

Comment: It is the type of the property value being passed, which could be something like string, int, or a custom type like States (see @salle55's answer). You could use typeof, like you indicated or perhaps something like value.GetType().

Answer (score 0):

in my case TypeConverter did not apply to States class

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(StatesList))] // not work
public class States
{
}
```

so i added override in CustomPropertyDescriptor

```
public override TypeConverter Converter
{
    get {
        if (this.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(States)) ) {
            return new StatesList(); ; 
        }
        return base.Converter;
    }
}
```